# How to create a selectable_column in nested custom page in ActiveAdmin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I want to make a table in my nested custom page that having selectable_column just like the index page in ActiveAdmin. But it seems selectable_column is only available in the index page.

Is there any other way to make a selectable_column in the nested custom page?

I have a PurchaseOrder model and a nested page called items. What I want to do is to change the state of each item through selectable_column and batch action.

```
# app/admin/purchase_order.rb
ActiveAdmin.register PurchaseOrder do
  member_action :items do
  end
end
```

Maybe having selectable_column inside the nested custom page.

```
# app/admin/purchase_orders/items.html.arb
panel "PO Items" do
  table_for resource.items do
    selectable_column
    column :product_id
    column :state
  end
end
```

Want to have selectable_column and batch actions that can help me update the state in one time like in the ActiveAdmin user index page.(sorry don't have enough reputation to post image) http://demo.activeadmin.info/admin/users

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

selectable_column is implemented in [IndexTableFor](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/95b8276d307aa86b7fbe27f870adfa24e5dbd378/lib/active_admin/views/index_as_table.rb#L272), a subclass of TableFor. Maybe you can `insert_tag IndexTableFor, resource.items do...` but I don't know any examples of that or what problem you would run into next.  I think a much less painful approach is to use [belongs_to](https://activeadmin.info/2-resource-customization.html#belongs-to) as far as possible.